# how to call Parameter-Less method in Groovy without braces

Tags: groovy

i can call method with parameter without braces 
example:- 
for  def method(args){}

we can call  it like
method " parameter"

but what if method does not have any parameter
 void method()

how to call it without  braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, you need the braces like `method()` as you say

Comment: I am trying to create a DSL using groovy and also i am new to groovy so i don't have deep knowledge of groovy as of now ,i don't want any programming complexity in DSL (like braces ,semicolon ) ,i am not using braces for some methods and using for some it is making DSL inconsistent ..is there any way by which i can call method or block of code which is not taking any parameter without any braces?

Comment: If you are writing an internal DSL, there might be some design options but that is more "white-board discussion" than "specific code question", and as such, better suited to Programmers Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can call only getters and setters without parameters.

E.g.:

```
getValue() {
    ...
}
```

may be called as

```
instance.value
```